# Want to create a conditional statement if someone chooses a specific template id.....to not echo the html code

Tags: php, html, sql

I am working with someone else's code.  It's a php MVC model website.   On a specific page, it echo's out code regardless of if I want it or not.   I would like to NOT echo the code if a specific templateID (that I have created) is chosen.  I have made that templateID the default, but don't know how to create the conditional statement in this situation.   I am a fairly new software developer and don't quite understand how to structure the elseif statement.

I tried creating an else if statement with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `template` WHERE `templateID` = 112 ORDER BY `templateID` ASC
```

```
if($_GET['e']) {
    $query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT templateID, name
    FROM template
    INNER JOIN exam ON examID = ".$_GET['e']."
    WHERE active = 'Yes'
    AND FIND_IN_SET(exam.type,template.templateType) > 0
    ORDER BY rank ASC, name ASC;";
}

else {
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE active = 'Yes' AND templateType LIKE '%General%' ORDER BY rank ASC, name ASC;";
}

$rows2 = $db->fetchAll($query2);

foreach($rows2 as $row2)
{
    $templates .= "<option value=".$row2['templateID'].">".$row2['name']."</option>\n";
}


echo 
"
<form method=POST name=Record>
<input type=hidden name=tempContents id=tempContents>
</form>

<form method=POST name=Comm id=CommForm>
<input type=hidden name=e value=\"".(int)$_GET['e']."\">
<div id=\"sendIds\"></div>
";

echo '
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><b>Template:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><select name=template onChange="changeTemplate(this)">'.$templates.'</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><b>Subject:</b></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><input type=text size=50 name=subject id=subject style="width:400px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;" valign=top><b>Attachments:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br><br><input type=button class=button value=Add onClick="newAttachment()"></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;" valign=top><div id=fileUploads></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><b>Message:</b></td>
    <td></td>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;" colspan=2>
    <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="tinymce">
    </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
';
```

Ideally, I'd like to create an elseif statement above that would result in my $query2 to be blank and result in me not getting an output of the echo

Do I need two conditional statements? 1 for the query and 1 for the echo?  How would I write them out?

Comment: If you are selecting by `\`templateID\` = 112` then what possible use would there be in sorting on `templateID` as it will only return `templateID's` that are `112` i.e. ALL EXACTLY THE SAME

Comment: What does `it echo's out code regardless of if I want it or not` mean? What code? Your problem isn't very clear.

Comment: Also, all your HTML attribute values should be quoted. Ex. `... method="post" name="Record">`

Comment: Right now, the website echo's the code listed above.   I am trying to find a way to have it not display unless I choose one of the other template id's besides the default one from the drop down.   Hope that makes sense.  :)  I realize that the "sort by" is useless.   That query was just copied from phpmyadmin.

Comment: So you only want to show the form once? If someone chooses a template then that should _stick_ and you shouldn't show the form again?

Comment: I only want to show the form if they choose a template other than id 112.  In other words, the form is obtrusive, but useful only if they want to send correspondence.   I don't want the form appearing to be a default.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. So just wrap _eveything_ in a conditional check. `if ($templateId <> '112') { ... }`. You can probably get rid of your `else` and 2nd query too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the correspondence form when the template is not the default, then wrap your entire form in a conditional check.

**Notes:**

- You're open to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries instead
- you should quote all of the HTML attributes
- your 2nd form is missing the closing form tag
- what's the point of the first form if the only field is hidden and there's no submit button?

Example:

```
<?php
if ($templateId <> '112') {

    if($_GET['e']) {
        $query = 'SELECT ...';
    } else {
        $query = 'SELECT ...';
    }

    foreach ($db->... as $row) {
        ...
    }

    echo '<form method="post" name="Comm" id="CommForm">...';
}
```